# The size of the Triceratops specimen Lane in the Houston Museum of Natural Science

Tags: palaeontology, dinosaurs

In 2012 the Houston Museum of Natural Science published they discovered an almost complete fossil of *Triceratops* including fossilized skin, see [HMNS post](http://blog.hmns.org/2012/05/introducing-lane-a-mummified-triceratops-with-a-new-address-at-5555-hermann-park-dr/), and nicknamed it "Lane".

I am interested to know the size of the Triceratops specimen Lane and in particular: total body length (TBL), total head length including the frill (THL) and brow (superorbital) horns cores length. Estimation of weight would also be great but I doubt if there are any.